# Collatz Conjecture, why an increment of $+6$ in the following?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, collatz-conjecture

Following my previous question at: [Collatz Conjecture, why a rate of change of $*4$ in the following?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022684/collatz-conjecture-why-a-rate-of-change-of-4-in-the-following)

Following the rules of the Collatz Conjecture, in this experiment I have created a list of all odd numbers until $33333$. The list includes 3 columns, such as in the following sample:

| A) Starting Odd $(X)$ | B) $(X * 3) +1$ | C) $X/2$ repeat until odd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2, (1) |
| 3 | 10 | (5) ** |
| 5 | 16 | 8, 4, 2, (1) |
| 7 | 22 | (11) ** |
| 9 | 28 | 14, (7) |
| 11 | 34 | (17) ** |
| 13 | 40 | 20, 10, (5) |
| 15 | 46 | (23) ** |
| 17 | 52 | 26 (13) |
| 19 | 58 | (29) ** |

...

You will notice that starting with $X=3$ in column A) and incrementing $X + 4$ in column A) will result in a consistent increment of $+6$ in column C) (marked by ** in the table). Why is that ?

Also the same doesn't apply when starting with $X=1$ in column A) and incrementing $X + 4$ in column A). Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines marked ** are those where the odd number is of the form $4k+3$  When you apply the Collatz iteration the first time you get $3(4k+3)+1=12k+10$.  This can only be divided by $2$ once, which is the second iteration.  Since the numbers of type $4k+3$ increment by $4$, after one iteration they increment by $12$ and after the second they iterate by $6$.  On the other hand, numbers of the form $4k+1$ will go to $12k+4$ and can be divided by $2$ at least twice on the second iteration.